# VBA to JAVA link

Tags: java, eclipse, vba, com, localhost

I'm currently trying to link a simulation program (written in VBA) to my JAVA application using COM2JAVA tool. I 'm facing couple problems and I hope to find someone to help in here..

1- The local host: I'm supposed to link my program to a specified simulation case, the way to do it in VBA is as follows:

```
Set hyCase = GetObject(“c:\samples\c-2.hsc”, “HYSYS.SimulationCase”)
```

through wrapping classes provided by COM2JAVA, I can have the following constructors:

```
Application(java.lang.String host)
```

Construct a Application on specified host.

OR

```
/**
   * Construct a SimulationCase on specified host.
   * @param     host  the host on which the object should be created
   * @exception java.io.IOException if there are problems communicating via DCOM 
   * @exception java.net.UnknownHostException if the host can not be found 
   */
  public SimulationCase(String host) throws java.io.IOException, java.net.UnknownHostException {
    d__SimulationCaseProxy = new hysys._SimulationCaseProxy(CLSID, host, null);
  }
```

The question is: how to specify the host and is it relevant to the path where my simulation case lives? I tried to feed it the path as host but it didn't work out (I know it might seem dumb :D )

2- I can't run the program on Eclipse because I have to type this command everytime I load the program on cmd:

```
java -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE Code
```

is there anyway to set that in Eclipse?

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007feff28118f, pid=3172, tid=0x0000000000000088
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [OLEAUT32.dll+0x118f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

Comment: that was part of the error log file